# Iterate mediator vs salesforce connector and queryMore quering duplicates

Tags: salesforce, wso2, connector, wso2-esb

I have an issue using queryMore from salesforce connector in wso2esb. I need to get all the records from Accounts then combine them into one message and further process it (convert to csv and save).

[Documentation for connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Salesforce+Connector#SalesforceConnector-Queryingrecords) says that I should use

```
    <salesforce.query>
        <batchSize>200</batchSize>
        <queryString>select id,name from Account</queryString>
    </salesforce.query>
    <!-- Execute the following to get the other batches -->
    <iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor" continueParent="true" expression="//sfdc:iterator">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <salesforce.queryMore>
                    <batchSize>200</batchSize>
                </salesforce.queryMore>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
```

but this never increment "queryLocator" and querying still the same batch over and over.

I tried to improve it like this:

```
<salesforce.query>
       <batchSize>200</batchSize>
       <queryString>select id,name from Account limit 2042</queryString>
</salesforce.query>

<property name="MujQueryLocator" expression="get-property('salesforce.query.queryLocator')" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
  <property name="FirstQuery" expression="get-property('salesforce.query.queryLocator')"/>
  <property xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" name="FirstQ --" expression="//ns:result/ns:queryLocator/text()"/>
   <property name="MyLocator" expression="get-property('operation','MujQueryLocator')"/>
</log>

<iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor" continueParent="true" expression="//sfdc:iterator" sequential="true">
   <target>
       <sequence>
           <property name="salesforce.query.queryLocator" expression="get-property('operation','MujQueryLocator')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

  <log level="custom">
      <property name=" BEFORE QueryMore" expression="get-property('salesforce.query.queryLocator')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" name=" second " expression="//ns:result/ns:queryLocator/text()"/>
      <property name="Muj locator -- " expression="get-property('operation','MujQueryLocator')"/>
  </log>

<salesforce.queryMore>
     <batchSize>200</batchSize>
</salesforce.queryMore>

<property xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" name="MujQueryLocator" expression="//ns:result/ns:queryLocator/text()" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>

<log level="custom">
  <property name="AFTER QueryMore" expression="get-property('salesforce.query.queryLocator')"/>
  <property xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" name="AFTER QM" expression="//ns:result/ns:queryLocator/text()"/>
  <property name="AFTER MyQueryLocator " expression="get-property('operation','MujQueryLocator')"/>
</log>

 <property xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" name="salesforce.query.queryLocator" expression="//ns:result/ns:queryLocator/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<log level="full"/>
                            <loopback/>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
                <respond/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <aggregate>
                    <completeCondition>
                        <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
                    </completeCondition>
                    <onComplete xmlns:ns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" expression="//ns:queryResponse|//ns:queryMoreResponse">
                        <enrich>
                            <source clone="true" xpath="//ns:records"/>
                            <target type="body" action="child"/>
                        </enrich>
                        <!-- HERE I WANTED FURTHER PROCESSING OF WHOLE MESSAGE>
                    </onComplete>
                </aggregate>
            </outSequence>
```

From now queryLocator is incrementing, but not always so it goes for the same query multiple times and therefore generating duplicate data. In aggregated message is only one of the responses and it never query for all the records in Account. See log:

```
[2015-08-11 17:16:49,240]  INFO - LogMediator Connection = Login to Salesforce .....

[2015-08-11 17:16:50,869]  INFO - EndAFTERintContext EndAFTERint : AnonymousEndAFTERint currently SUSPENDED will now be marked active since it processed its last message

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,553]  INFO - LogMediator PrvniQuery = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200, PrvniQuery vytazena -- = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200, MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,572]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,588]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,722]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,847]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:52,982]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,107]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,247]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-200

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,274]  INFO - LogMediator --> AFTER QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, -- AFTER QM in msg = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,281]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:112d95e0-df2c-4d39-acdc-88f0a3e82249, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header><LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>3390</current><limit>15000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><queryMoreResAFTERnse><result xsi:type="QueryResult"><done>false</done><queryLocator>01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400</queryLocator><records /records><size>2042</size></result></queryMoreResAFTERnse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,419]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,576]  INFO - LogMediator  BEFORE QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400,  BEFORE QM in msg = , MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,674]  INFO - LogMediator --> AFTER QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, -- AFTER QM in msg = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

...again message for 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,810]  INFO - LogMediator --> AFTER QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, -- AFTER QM in msg = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

...again message for 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

[2015-08-11 17:16:53,810]  INFO - LogMediator --> AFTER QueryMore = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, -- AFTER QM in msg -- = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400, MyQueryLocator  = 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-400

....
.....after some time and repeats it increments to 01gb0000023KfHsAAK-600
...and so on
```

Another thing I don't know is how to combine responses from salesforce.query and those form salesforce.queryMore

ESB version 4.8.1

Is somebody able to explain me this behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your description, my understanding is what you want to do is a "do-while" loop. I´ve faced a simular situation recently and the only solution I´ve found was to create a service that sends a message to itself at the end.

In my case I´ve used this message in order to pass the some paging parameters (start record and page size), which in the Salesforce case are equivalent to the batchSize and query locator parameters.

The pseudo code for the proxy is something like that:

```
if ( first call ) then
    do "query" api call;
else
    set "salesforce.query.queryLocator" property from request data;
    do "query more" api call;
end if;

process query results;

if ( "salesforce.query.done" property is not 'true') then
   create continuation message using the value of
   'salesforce.query.queryLocator' property;
   send one-way message to ESB;
end if;
```

Please note that this approach only work in scenarios where the mediation sequence is started by a scheduled task or a client that is only used to trigger the first call.

Answer (score 0):

With ESB 490 and latest salesforce connector you can achive this using iterator mediator. Find the sample.

```
     <salesforce.init>
        <username>xxxxxx@gmail.com</username>
        <password>xxxxxx</password>
<loginUrl>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0</loginUrl>
        <blocking>true</blocking>
     </salesforce.init>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="salesforce" value="logged in, executing query"/>
     </log>
     <salesforce.query>
        <batchSize>20</batchSize>
        <queryString>select id,name from Account</queryString>
     </salesforce.query>
     <property name="opt.salesforce.query.queryLocator"
               expression="$ctx:salesforce.query.queryLocator"
               scope="operation"
               type="STRING"/>

     <iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor"
              expression="//sfdc:iterator"
              sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <property name="salesforce.query.queryLocator"
                        expression="get-property('operation','opt.salesforce.query.queryLocator')"
                        type="STRING"/>
              <log level="custom">
                 <property name="Before ......................"
                           expression="$ctx:salesforce.query.queryLocator"/>
              </log>
              <salesforce.queryMore>
                 <batchSize>20</batchSize>
              </salesforce.queryMore>
              <property name="opt.salesforce.query.queryLocator"
                        expression="$ctx:salesforce.query.queryLocator"
                        scope="operation"
                        type="STRING"/>
              <log level="custom">
                 <property name="After ......................"
                           expression="$ctx:salesforce.query.queryLocator"/>
              </log>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. And this is the only solution before esb 490. With esb 490 blocking calls were introduced and with this we can support do-while with iterator.

The method you suggested (recursive calls) has a limit on number of querymore calls which is not the case with iterator mediator.